# Appengine (python) returns empty for valid queries

Tags: python, google-app-engine

EDIT: Figured it out. For whatever reason the field in the index was called strWord instead of wordStr. I didn't notice because of the similarities. The file was auto generated, so I must have called the field that in a previous development version.

I've got an app with around half a million 'records', each of which only stores three fields. I'd like to look up records by a string field with a query, but I'm running into problems. If I visit the console page, manually view a record and save it (without making changes) it shows up in a query:

SELECT * FROM wordEntry WHERE wordStr = 'SomeString'

If I don't do this, I get 'no results'. Does appengine need time to update? If so, how much?
(I was also having trouble batch deleting and modifying data, but I was able to break the problem up into smaller chunks.)

Answer (score 0):

When this has happened to me it's because I've been using a `TextField`, which cannot be queried (but confusingly just gets ignored).  Try switching to `StringField`.

Comment: Right now it's a string property :/
wordStr = db.StringProperty(multiline = False)